# COALESCE in subquery still returns DBnull

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

Unfortunately i am facing today another bug which i don't understand.
I'm selecting the next and previous id from my database and i am using COALESCE to replace a null value with a number. 
But for some reason it still returns null, am i missing something?

```
"Select Gags.Title, Gags.DatePosted, Gags.Image, Users.Username, (Select Top(1) COALESCE(Id, 0) from Gags where Id > " + IdModel.Id + "), (Select Top(1) COALESCE(Id, 0) from Gags where Id < " + IdModel.Id + ") From Gags Inner Join Users on Gags.Userid = Users.Id where Gags.Id = " + IdModel.Id + "
```

Fixed Query:

```
Select Gags.Title, Gags.DatePosted, Gags.Image, Users.Username, isnull((Select Top(1) id from Gags where Id > " + IdModel.Id + "),-1), Isnull((Select Top(1) id from Gags where Id < " + IdModel.Id + "), -1) From Gags Inner Join Users on Gags.Userid = Users.Id where Gags.Id = " + IdModel.Id + "
```

I'm talking about the two sub queries.

Thanks in advance!

It's a terrible programming day today ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an empty rowset, `coalesce` won't be invoked:

```
(select top 1 coalesce(Id, 0) from ...)
```

And an empty rowset in a scalar context returns `null`:

```
select (select 1 where 1=0)
-->
NULL
```

One solution is to move the `coalesce` outside the subquery:

```
coalesce((select top 1 Id from ...),0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know the isnull or coalesce had to be outside the sub query!

Comment: @Andomar . . . As a note, this is one place where you *shouldn't* use `coalesce()` (which I otherwise always advocate).  Apparently, there is a bug in SQL Server (or at least some versions) that causes the first argument of `coalesce()` to be executed twice when the value is not `NULL`.  For this reason, `isnull()` is preferred here.  Here are more details:  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/.